# Laravel Homestead // npm install --no-bin-links // Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, laravel-5, homestead

When running a *fresh* Laravel 5.4 installation with Homestead and Vagrant in a Windows 10 host machine, I get a npm error when I run the **npm install --no-bin-links** command saying:

*Maximum call stack size exceeded*.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I found a solution and posted it here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/41919481/3099449